# How to check if words in a list match words in a string

Tags: regex, flutter, dart, match

I have a list of words which are in a list of string

```
List<String> badWords = [
  "bad", 
  "damn",
  //and other list of offensive words too
];
```

Now if I have a string which is gotten from the user through input, I want to loop through the list and check if any of those words match any word on the string maybe by using regex eg

```
String text = msgController.text;
badWords.map((e) {
  //If any the words in the text matches any of the words in the list then print those words out
}).toList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest splitting sentence and see if array contains bad words. Too make it more fancy, we can use regex to split by multiple characters. Below full working example with comments:

```
void main() {
  List<String> badWords = [
    "bad", "damn", //and other list of offensive words too
  ];
  List<String> sentences = [
    "bad developer, you broke production",
    "good dev, you did good job",
    "damn devs, they brake stuff"
  ];
  for(String sentence in sentences){
    if(isSentenceOffensive(sentence, badWords)){
      print('$sentence - is offensive!');
    }
  }
}

bool isSentenceOffensive(String sentence, List<String> badWords)
{
  /* here we use regex to split by either dot (.), comma (,), or space ( ) */
  List<String> words = sentence.split(RegExp(r"[., ]"));
  for (String word in words){
    if(badWords.contains(word)){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Output of above is:

```
bad developer, you broke production - is offensive!
damn devs, they brake stuff - is offensive!
```

Answer (score 1):

I would simply iterate over the list and check if the string contains any of the words.

```
String text = msgController.text
for (var i in badWords) {
  if (text.contains(i)){
    // Do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are pretty spot on, `.contains()` is what I'd use to check against the `badWords` list. If you split `text` on spaces and store that in another list, you can iterate through that list and check if each word exists in the `badWords` list. Here's a possible way of doing it:

```
List<String> badWords = [
  "bad", 
  "damn",
  // and other list of offensive words too
];

String text = msgController.text;
final textWords = text.split(' ');

for(final word in textWords) {
  if (badWords.contains(word.toLowerCase())) {
    // do a thing with the bad word
    print(word);
  }
}
```

It's also worth noting that by iterating through the text instead of `badWords`, you can call `.toLowerCase()` to ensure that you're checking for bad words without case sensitivity (as long as you store all values in `badWords` in lower case).

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a RegExp because it gives a way to only match *whole* words, and you don't want to disallow a strings like "badminton" or "assassin" just because they contain a bad word. It also makes it easy to ignore case, which you likely also want to do.

```dart
  var badWordsRE = RegExp("\\b(?:${badWords.join("|")})\\b", caseSensitive: false);

  bool containsBadWords = badWordsRE.hasMatch(string);
```

The `\b` only matches at a word boundary, so `"bad"` won't be found in `"badminton"`.

This assumes that the `badWords` list only contains letters and symbols that are not meaningful in a RegExp, so if you try to capture ASCII art or similar, you'll likely need to escape them:

```dart
var badWordsRE = RegExp(
    "\\b(?:${badWords.map(RegExp.escape).join("|")})\\b", 
    caseSensitive: false);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `list.contains(x)`;

for more you can read [here](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.0.0/dart-core/Iterable/contains.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
void main()
{
  List<String> stringlist = [
    // list of string data. here is the name
    'zeshan',
    'abid',
    'ali',
  ];
  
  // "zeshan" is the new string 
  print(stringlist.contains('zeshan'),);
}
```

result of this will be ..
true.